# java-grpc: How to increase the message size limit in a ManagedChannel?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Our communication exceeds the default [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) limit on the message size:

```
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL:
Frame size 4555602 exceeds maximum: 4194304.
If this is normal, increase the maxMessageSize
in the channel/server builder
```

That limit can be increased, see from https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/917:

> Set maxMessageSize() on the Channel/Server builder.

When trying to implement the fix in our code base, however, it is not clear for me how to do that, as not all `Channel` implementations have a `maxMessageSize` method.

Our code uses a [`ManagedChannel`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannel.html). The setup code looks like this:

```
ManagedChannel channel = 
   ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(rpcHost, grpcPort)
                        .usePlaintext(true).build();

CatalogGrpcServiceGrpc.CatalogGrpcServiceBlockingStub stub =
    CatalogGrpcServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
CatalogRetrieverGrpcServiceAdapter grpcServiceAdapter =
    new CatalogRetrieverGrpcServiceAdapter(
            stub, metricRegistry);
```

Maybe I am missing something, but I cannot see how to increase the maximum size for `ManagedChannel`. Only the `OkHttpChannelBuilder` has it ([`OkHttpChannelBuilder#maxMessageSize`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/io/grpc/okhttp/OkHttpChannelBuilder.java#L224)).

**Questions:**

- How can I increase the message limit with a `ManagedChannel`?
- If it is not possible with `ManagedChannel`, how can I rewrite the code to use another channel implementation that support to increase the default limit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: You can now increase the limit directly from `ManagedChannelBuilder`.

Today, you can't increase the limit on `ManagedChannelBuilder`; you are forced to specify the transport implementation you want to use.

So most users would explicitly use `NettyChannelBuilder`, and Android users would use `OkHttpChannelBuilder`:

```
ManagedChannel channel = 
   NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(rpcHost, grpcPort)
                        .usePlaintext(true).build();
```

I've created [GitHub issue 2307](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2307) to track this.

Answer (score 3):

You can increase gRPC message limit using **maxInboundMessageSize()**:

```java
ManagedChannel channel = 
   ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(rpcHost, grpcPort)
                        .usePlaintext(true)
                        .maxInboundMessageSize(1000000) // enter the size here
                        .build();
```

Comment: `maxInboundMessageSize` is ignored in my case. Which grpcVersion are you using?

Comment: I don't have the configuration anymore but believe it was v1.51